# How to use gcc to compile multiple different source .c files into differently named executables

Tags: c, gcc

Wow, what a title.  I need help either creating a makefile, or simply figuring out the gcc command for the following.  It has very specific specifications which need to be met.

I have 6 source files, called AA.c, BB.c, CC.c, DD.c, EE.c, and FF.c.  I need to compile these such that the executables are named as AA, BB, CC, DD, EE, and FF, respectively.

This is because AA.c calls other executables from within, which are named with hardcoded values.  Thus, the executables must be named as I listed above, or AA will throw error and not run.

Then the user can simply type AA at the console.

Not sure if .out is needed to be present past the end of each executable name, if so, that is perfectly fine as it can be modified easily.

Comment: Have you tried running `make AA`? GNU Make comes with implicit rules, one of which builds the binary AA from AA.c. Also, is the PATH an issue? 'Cuz you gotta put binaries in one of the PATH directories for `AA` alone to run AA. edit: not one, but two implicit rules https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html

Comment: No, I have not tried running make AA.  I am not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would do it with GNU make:

```
all: $(patsubst %.c,%,$(wildcard *.c))

%: %.o
        $(CC) -o $@ $<
```

Or if you have other `.c` files too and just want the 6 you listed to be compiled as programs, make the first line:

```
all: AA BB CC DD EE FF
```

Comment: I believe you should use `$(COMPILE.c)` instead of `$(CC)`, or at least you should use `$(CFLAGS)` and you should have `CFLAGS= -Wall -g`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: `CFLAGS` is for compiling. That command line is purely a linker command line. The compiler rule is built-in. `$(COMPILE.c)` is completely nonstandard and honestly something I've never seen before. `$(CC)` is the standard name for the command which is used (with the standard argument form, some of which is described in POSIX and the rest of which is de facto standard by historical practice in GCC and vendor-provided compilers) to invoke the compiler and linker.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Again that's some sort of nonstandard usage that's unfriendly to users. `CC` is the standard variable you set to tell the build process the command to use for compiling/linking. Using nonstandard variable names is just going to gratuitously break things for people trying to cross-compile or use a non-default compiler (e.g. to compare output with gcc-4.8 and gcc-4.9) to build.

Comment: No, it is GNU make specific. Try `make -p`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Indeed, the default GNU make definitions for `COMPILE.c`, `LINK.c`, etc. are defined in terms of `$(CC)`, so they should respect user preference. I was not aware of these variables. Assuming they've been around since the earliest GNU make versions still in widespread use, I drop my objection to their usage, but I still think they're rather unconventional. Do you have any links to information on the experiences of people who've used them in projects?

Answer (score -1):

```
I have a pair of make files that produce one executable for each sub directory 
IMO: the best layout is one executable per directory.

Top level make file: makefile.mak
------------------

SHELL = /bin/sh




SRC := $(wildcard *.c)
OBJ := $(SRC:.c=.o)
DEP := $(SRC:.c=.d)
INC := $(SRC:.c=.h)


MAKE    :=  /usr/bin/make

CC      :=  /usr/bin/gcc

CP      :=  cp

MV      :=  mv

LDFLAGS :=  -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/lib

DEBUG   :=  -ggdb3

CCFLAGS :=  $(DEBUG) -Wall -W

#CPPFLAGS += =MD

LIBS    :=  -lssl -ldl -lrt -lz -lc -lm



.PHONY: AllDirectories
# the following statement needs to be edited as 
# subdirectories are added/deleted/re-named
#AllDirectories := \
#    Command_Configuration \
#    Communication \
#    Main_Scheduler \
#    Retrieve_CDS_Log \
#    Retrieve_EventRecorder_Log \
#    Retrieve_GPS \
#    Retrieve_QES_Alarm_Log \
#    Retrieve_QES_RealTime \
#    Write_CDS_Log

AllDirectories :=  \
    Main_Scheduler \
    Communication  \
    Retrieve_GPS   \
    Test_Communication_Dev 



.PHONY: all
all: $(OBJ) $(AllDirectories)
    $(foreach d,$(AllDirectories), \
    ( cd $d && $(MAKE) -f ../makefile.bot name=Tsk_$d all ); )



#
# create dependancy files
#
%.d: %.c
    # 
    # ========= START $< TO $@ =========
    $(CC) -M $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$;                      \
    sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@;     \
    rm -f $@.$$$$
    # ========= END $< TO $@ =========



#
# compile the .c file into .o files using the compiler flags
#
%.o: %.c %.d 
    # 
    # ========= START $< TO $@ =========
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -I. 
    # ========= END $< TO $@ =========
    # 



.PHONY: clean
clean: $(AllDirectories)
    # ========== start clean activities ==========
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f $(name).map
    rm -f $(name)
    rm -f *.d
    rm -f ../bin/Tsk_*
    $(foreach d,$(AllDirectories), \
    ( cd $d && $(MAKE) -f ../makefile.bot name=Tsk_$d clean ); )
    # ========== end clean activities ==========



.PHONY: install
#install: $(AllDirectories)
#   # ========== start install activities ==========
#   $(foreach d,$(AllDirectories), \
#    ( cd $d && $(MAKE) -f makefile.mak clean ); )
#   # ========== end install activities ==========

install: $(AllDirectories)
    # ========== start install activities ==========
    $(foreach d,$(AllDirectories), \
    ( cd $d && $(MAKE) -f ../makefile.bot name=Tsk_$d install ); )
    # ========== end install activities ==========



# include the contents of all the .d files
# note: the .d files contain:
# <filename>.o:<filename>.c plus all the dependancies for that file 
# I.E. the #include'd header files
# wrap with ifneg... so will not rebuild *.d files when goal is 'clean'
#
ifneq "$(MAKECMDGOALS)" "clean"
-include $(DEP)
endif
--------------

the second make file performs the actual make in each sub directory
--------------

SHELL = /bin/sh


BINDIR  :=  /home/user/bin


.PHONY: all
all : $(BINDIR)/$(name) ../makefile.mak ../makefile.bot


#
# macro of all *.c files 
# (NOTE:
# (the following 'wildcard' will pick up ALL .c files
# (like FileHeader.c and FunctionHeader.c 
# (which should not be part of the build
# (so be sure no unwanted .c files in directory
# (or change the extension
#
SRC := $(wildcard *.c)
OBJ := $(SRC:.c=.o)
DEP := $(SRC:.c=.d)
INC := $(SRC:.c=.h)


COMMON_OBJ := $(wildcard ../*.o)
#COMMON_SRC := $(wildcard ../*.c)
#COMMON_OBJ := $(COMMON_SRC:.c=.o)
#COMMON_DEP := $(COMMON_SRC:.c=.d)
#COMMON_INC := $(COMMON_SRC:.c=.h)

MAKE    :=  /usr/bin/make

CC      :=  /usr/bin/gcc

CP      :=  cp

MV      := mv

LDFLAGS :=  -L/usr/local/lib

DEBUG   :=  -ggdb3

CCFLAGS :=  $(DEBUG) -Wall -W

#CPPFLAGS += =MD

#LIBS    :=  -lidn -lssl -ldl -lrt -lz -lc -lm
LIBS    :=   -lssl -ldl -lrt -lz -lc -lm



#
# link the .o files into the executable 
# using the linker flags
# -- explicit rule
#
$(name): $(OBJ) $(COMMON_OBJ) ../makefile.mak ../makefile.bot
    #
    # ======= $(name) Link Start =========
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJ) $(COMMON_OBJ) $(LIBS)
    # ======= $(name) Link Done ==========
    #



# note:
# using MV rather than CP results in all executables being re-made everytime
$(BINDIR)/$(name): $(name)
    #
    # ======= $(name) Copy Start =========
    sudo $(CP) $(name) $(BINDIR)/.
    # ======= $(name) Copy Done ==========
    #



#
#create dependancy files -- inference rule
# list makefile.mak as dependancy so changing makfile forces rebuild
#
%.d: %.c 
    # 
    # ========= START $< TO $@ =========
    $(CC) -M $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$;                      \
    sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@;     \
    rm -f $@.$$$$
    # ========= END $< TO $@ =========



# 
# compile the .c file into .o files using the compiler flags
# -- inference rule
#
%.o: %.c %.d 
    # 
    # ========= START $< TO $@ =========
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -I. 
    # ========= END $< TO $@ =========
    # 



.PHONY: clean
clean: 
    # ========== CLEANING UP ==========
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f $(name).map
    rm -f $(name)
    rm -f *.d
    # ========== DONE ==========



.PHONY: install
install: all

# include the contents of all the .d files
# note: the .d files contain:
# <filename>.o:<filename>.c plus all the dependancies for that .c file 
# I.E. the #include'd header files
# wrap with ifneg... so will not rebuild *.d files when goal is 'clean'
#
ifneq "$(MAKECMDGOALS)" "clean"
-include $(DEP)
endif
-----------------
```

Comment: You should never set `CC`, etc. yourself in a makefile like this. The whole point of using the variable is that it's taken from the defaults on the system where the build is taking place, or the command line or environment variables, as per the user's invocation of make. If you're going to hard-code it you might as well not use a variable. Also this makefile is hideously long and full of junk that provides no functionality; makefiles like this are a large part of why people irrationally hate make.